Converting string with T and Z to timestamp in BigQ
I have a string column in BigQ where I would like to convert to a timestamp, the column is currently saved in this format - 2024-02-26T09:48:23.842Z. The T and Z is what's throwing me off, not sure what the best way it is to convert to 2024-02-26 09:48:23.842
I assume some sort of PARSE_DATETIME would work but the T and Z has got me stuck.

Hi @tl1310, Can you try this query for your requirement: select PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ', '2024-02-26T09:48:23.842Z') .To remove UTC try this:
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E*S', PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ', '2024-02-26T09:48:23.842Z')) AS timestamp.Please let me know if this helps you.
